# ImportError: No module named 'pydub'

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pydub

I am creating a simple script that will use `pydub` to fetch files from a directory based on their name, then stitch a few of them together and export the result.

I had the script working great in a Windows environment (Win 7, python 3.4), but now I'm trying to run on OSX.

I have installed all necessary components - `ffmpeg`, `libav`.  I have just installed `pydub` with `pip`, pulling directly from [github](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/).

My file starts with the input statement `from pydub import AudioSegment`, and this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pydub import AudioSegment
ImportError: No module named 'pydub'
```

Thoughts?  What am I missing? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd appreciate an explanation for the anonymous downvote. Why do that?

Comment: Because your question is to broad. I am not the one who down voted it but I think it need more information and a copy of the code to see where things are breaking.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying @Ondeckshooting.  That was much more helpful. Definitely still learning how to ask good questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out [PEP 0394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/). You might be running `$ python functions.py` when you need to be running `$ python3 functions.py`. If that's the case, make sure you `$ pip3 install pydub`, otherwise OSX will not add the package to the right python version.

Comment: Spot on.  Reinstalled using `pip3` as described and we are rocking and rolling.  Thank you!

Comment: In my case I was using `#!/usr/bin/env python` instead of `#!/usr/bin/env python3`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue after installing the pydub vai:

```py
pip install pydub
```

then I use both via pip and pip3 and error gone

```py
pip 3 install pydub
pip install pydub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to install with pip3

```
pip3 install pydub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the below command in your terminal,

```
pip install pydub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2, just run

```
pip2 install pydub
```

Answer (score 0):

for me none of the above worked. I had to completely delete all instances of anaconda.

All instances of python.

And then reinstall python and reinstall jupyter notebooks. And then it started working and the pydub package reinstalled and the import started working.